# This is not a monad, right?

Tags: clojure, monads, identity

I've seen two sources that say the following is an identity monad. But I don't think that's true because it fails the Third Monad Law.

```
(defn result [v] (fn [] v))
(defn bind [mv f] (f (mv))
```

Fails the Third Monad Law

```
(bind (bind (result 3) identity) identity)
```

The inner bind call returns 3, which is not a monadic value, so Java returns the error of trying to call the function (3).

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The definitions of `bind` and `result` are fine, and do constitute a monad. However, `identity` is not a legal function to pass to `bind` for your monad. In Haskell, that would not pass the typechecker, because

```
bind :: (Monad m) => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
```

The second argument here is your `f`, in this case `identity`. But `identity :: a -> a` does not fit with the type required for `bind`'s `f`.

In order to use something "identity-like" in your monad, you need to lift `identity` into the monad by composing it with `result`. For example,

```
(let [id (comp result identity)] ;; or (liftm identity), if you have liftm
  (bind (bind (result 3) id) id))
```

returns `(result 3)`, ie `(fn [] 3)`.

### Edit

I did some more thinking about this, since my assertion that `a -> a` is an incompatible type with `a -> m b` is clearly not quite right: if you let `a` be `m b`, the types do match. So it's okay to use `identity` as the `bind` function in some cases. Specifically, if your original input is `(result (result 3))`, you can `bind` `identity` and get out just `(result 3)`. In fact, `(bind identity x)` is basically `(join x)`! This is not exactly news - I've read it multiple times - but I guess it hadn't sunk in, or I'd have answered this question more correctly to begin with.

Anyway, just thought I'd share this, since it's a bit topical and should flesh out my answer a bit.